# If x is 3 higher than y

Tags: python, string, numbers

I'm doing a program to do a guessing game; I need to be able to make the program give feedback of H or L only if a number is 3 higher than the random number or 3 less.

This is what I currently have

```
import random
def game3():
    rndnumber = str(random.randint(0,9999)) #gets a number between 0-9999
    while len(rndnumber) < 4: 
        rndnumber = '0'+ rndnumber # adds 0s incase the number is less then a 1000
    print(rndnumber) #lets me know that the program generates the right type of number (remove this after testing)
    feedback = 0 #adds a variable
    for x in range(1,11): #makes a loop that runs for 10 times
        print("Attempt",x)
        attempt = input("Guess a number between 0-9999:")#gets the users guess
        feedback = "" #makes a feedback variable
        for y in range(4): #makes a loop that runs for 4 times
            if attempt[y] == rndnumber[y]: #if attempt is the same then add a Y to the number
                feedback += "Y"
            elif attempt[y] < rndnumber[y]:
                feedback += "L"
            elif attempt[y] > rndnumber[y]:
                feedback += "H"
            else:
                feedback += "N"
        print(feedback)
        if  x == 10:
            print("You Lose the correct answer was",rndnumber)
        if feedback == "YYYY" and x > 1:
            print("You win it took",x,"attempts.")
            break; #stops the program
        elif feedback == "YYYY":
            print("You won on your first attempt!")
            break; #stops the program
```

Comment: Something I realized when I began to learn programming is that there two ways to write things out, name things, reason things, etc: *First*, there is your way. *Then*, there is the right way. When you name your variables, first you'll start with your own names, they may be long but they make sense to you. The problem is that none of the help you get will be in your mental language and you'll have to translate a lot. Eventually, the more popular naming conventions and logical methods will be easier for you. Take my advice and learn the popular way to do things now; It makes learning much easier

Comment: Why are you comparing numbers by comparing individual digits in a loop? Why not just compare the whole number with `if attempt == rndnumber`?

Comment: @Barmar Because he's programming something similar to Mastermind.

Comment: if I compare each number I can then give feedback like below
Guess a number between 0-9999:1523
HLLY

Comment: It needs to start from 0, but have 4 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use

```
if attempt == rndnumber + 3 or attempt == rndnumber - 3:
    # Do something...
```

Comment: When I attempt to do this I get this error

'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I'm not sure where that error is coming from - but since you are working with them as strings, you'll need to wrap both variables in an `int` conversion in order to be able to add and subtract 3.

Comment: When I do this, I still get the same error, Would it have to do with having my rndnumber as a str before?

Comment: Can you give the line number that the error message gives you?

Comment: line 13, in game3
    if attempt[y] == rndnumber[y]: #if attempt is the same then add a Y to the number
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Oh, because you are converting to an integer and not converting back. If you want to use `+` and `-` and `*` your variable has to be an integer. But if you want to use `[]` it has to be a string (or a list). So, leave it as a string and just do `if int(attempt) == int(rndnumber) + 3 ...`.

Answer (score 0):

> If x is 3 higher than y

```
if x+3 == y:
    #code
```

> the program give feedback only if a number is 3 higher than the random
>   number or 3 less.

```
if x+3 == y or x-3 == y:
    #give feedback
```

Source:

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html

Answer (score 0):

In line 10 you save a string in the variable attempt.
In line 13 however, you use attempt as a dictionary.

You might want to rethink your whole approach here.

Edit:

Of course I also did a guessing game at one point. While I would definitely use a different approach nowadays, I think it might be helpful for you and build your requirements for your own game in this python 3 code.

```
import random

print ("Hello! What is your name?")
name = input()
print ("Well,", name, ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.\nTake a guess.")
number = random.randint(1, 100) # create a number between 1 and 100
guess = input() # read user's guess
guess = int(guess)
guessnumber = 1 # first try to guess the number
guessed = False # number isn't guessed yet
while guessed == False:
    if (number == guess):
        print ("Good job,", name + "! You guessed my number in",guessnumber, "guesses!")
        guessed = True
    elif (guess > number):
        print ("Your guess is too high.")
        guess = input("Take another guess: ")
        guess = int(guess)
        guessnumber+=1
    else:
        print ("Your guess is too low.")
        guess = input("Take another guess: ")
        guess = int(guess)
        guessnumber+=1
```

Comment: I feel as though his code already largely resembles this structure.